# domain SSO (win -> linux -> AD)

Tags: linux, active-directory, single-sign-on

i have this situation:
windows domain (+active directory) (2008),
linux machine (debian, redhat),
and windows work stations (xp, vista, 7).

users are connecting to linux from win PCs using ssh (putty). thah means, thay must type username and password on every login.

my goal is create SSO. users login to windows(and domain) on startup (by domain name+pass), and when they are connecting to linux machine no password is required. i need configure linux machine. and make same changes in putty-core application in worstations. biggest problem is configure linux.

need some help

maybe using kerberos??

thanks

Comment: Please go to serverfault.com. I'd know what to do but this is the wrong place.

Comment: You can configure putty to auto login by following the 4 pages of steps from here. http://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_putty

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn, pointless advice, he's not talking about SSH keys.

Comment: err he was looking for options. see the question marks??

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to use Centrify DirectControl Express and Centrify Putty (both FREE). Centrify DirectControl Express allows you to quickly and easily join a non-Microsoft system to an Active Directory domain, thereby giving you the advantage of a single administrative tool to administer authentication across a heterogeneous computing environment.

Distribute Centrify-Enabled Putty to your windows users, to be able to SSO into the Linux machines.

For more information, refer to:

http://www.centrify.com/express/centrify-directcontrol-express.asp
http://www.centrify.com/express/centrify-enabled-open-source-tools.asp